# Splinter wait for element.visible

Tags: django, testing, splinter

I have some anoying behaviour with splinter. I do

```
button.click()
assert not button.visible  # Fails
```

Then I do

```
button.click()
time.sleep(1)
assert not button.visible  # Succeeds
```

That is pretty bad... Is this intended behaviour? Everything else seems to poll and wait for a bit before it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Splinter works internally, but looks like you are using an attribute access and it might be cached. Have you tried:

```
 assert not browser.is_element_visible_by_css("#my-button-id")
```

`is_element_visible_by_css` has always an implicit wait you can configure in Splinter settings. Please note that with browser (Selenium) testing everything has implicit waits, as browser DOM operations happen asynchronously and there is no backchannel to get information when some element becomes visible or when it disappears.

Comment: No such method exists (http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html). Is there a way to drop through splinter to selenium and get that method?

Comment: Woops, my bad. Try this: "Re-get" the element by calling `b.find_element_by_css()` and then check `visible` again. I am checking what has happened for this method, I have had it in my code in past.

Comment: The method is here, but looks like it is undocumented https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/04a6da307f76d872ef1c227c47509fc983e5315c/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L220

Comment: And it has implicit wait https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/04a6da307f76d872ef1c227c47509fc983e5315c/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py#L201